# Created starburst effect using Wave and Polar Coordinates, but it doesn't tile

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

I'm creating a silly anthropomorphic router by heavily modifying a product image of a Linksys router. Here's a preview.

[image]

I want to incorporate a [starburst effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ9l9zDXTgE) into the background by creating a layer with a linear white-to-transparent gradient, applying Wave and finishing with Polar Coordinates. Here's what my first attempt looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there's an unwanted artifact going from the center to the top of the layer. I'm assuming this is because the output from the Wave filter didn't tile horizontally. Is there a smart way to adjust the settings of the Wave effect so that I don't have to fix it up manually? I'm using Photoshop Elements 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the type of burst that you are doing, I would do this:

1. Select `Shape Tool` and this shape [image] ( One of the default shapes ).
2. Place it in the document center ( <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> > <kbd>v</kbd> and then align vertical and horizontal centers ). [image]
3. Top menu `Filter > Blur > Gaussian blur...` ( or you can do this after step #5 if you want.. Or not at all, if you want sharper edges ) [image]
4. Top menu `Filter > Blur > Radial blur...` [image]
5. Apply previous filter as many times as needed <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> [image]